# Pass struct with c strings from vb6

Tags: dll, vb6, interop, dllimport

this seems like a simple question but I can't seem to google up the answer. I have a dll that has an interface like this:

```
struct TestResults
{
    int StringLengths;
    Error Error;
    LPTSTR SerialNumber;
    LPTSTR Application;
    LPTSTR GSM;
};

extern "C" Error DLLNAME_ _stdcall GetResult(TestResults* testResults);
```

The dll will fill in the several strings.
How can I use this interface from VB6?  How can I initialize the strings to use for example a 64 character long fixed length string?

Comment: The strings are easy enough, you just need to preallocate them.  But what is the definition of 'Error' in your struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `Error` is defined as a 32-bit integer, which means that in VB your Type should look like:

```
Type ResultsType
    StringLengths As Long
    ErrorValue As Long
    SerialNumber As Long
    Application As Long
    GSM As Long
End Type
```

`Dim testResults As ResultsType`

Each of the strings should be a pre-sized variable-length string, like;

```
Dim strGSM as String
strGSM = String$(64, 0)
testResults.GSM = StrPtr(strGSM)
```

The Declaration would be:

```
Declare Function GetResult Lib "DLLNAME" (ByVal testResults As ResultsType) As Long
```

The return value would be the `Error` value described above. The `Lib` field assumes the DLL is in your path -- if not, you can qualify it further.

All that's air code, no guarantees since it isn't tested.

Comment: You can use regular VB6 String variables for the LPTSTR as long as you pre-allocate them with `String$(64, 0)` as you pointed out.  VB6 knows how to marshal those.

Comment: @tcarvin  Yes, but in the case of a LPTSTR the DLL may be expecting Wide strings and standard marshaling will pass Ansi (narrowed) BSTR. I guess the OP would have to experiment if it isn't documented which is expected.

Comment: That's true.  Either way the developer will need to know that answer, as if it is really a LPSTR then this code above is not going to work since VB6 will expect that string being pointed to be unicode and it won't be.